# linux find no such file or directory but exists

Tags: linux, unix, find

Then i trying to use this script

```
for line in `cat dirs.txt`; 
do 
find "$line" -type f \( -name '*good*' -o -exec grep -F "badbad" {} \; \) -exec echo {} \;; 
done
```

I get error on each existing dirs and match the find criteria

> ```
> find: /home/goods/ : No such file or directory 
> find: /home/bads/ : No such file or directory 
> find: /home/fill/ : No such file or directory
> ```

But then i look manualy this dirs exist and i can read them all
Why this happens?

Comment: Are you sure that these directories are in `/home/` and not in `/home/[username]/`?

Comment: But then i look manualy this dirs exist and i can read them all!!!

Comment: In the `dirs.txt` file, do you have extra blanks at the end of each line?

Comment: i think about this, but i cant see them, and trying retype manually each dirname.

Comment: Not sure if your second comment was responding to `Tom`? You're saying those home directories exist? If so please provide output of `cat -vET dirs.txt`

Comment: cat -vET dirs.txt each string have ^M$ on the end  except last one which i can see in script output like founded

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin Those are dos eols. Run `dos2unix dirs.txt dirs.txt`, then try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check in file for ^M$

You can do that with command `cat dirs.txt -vET`

Then you must trim them all with command `cat dirs.txt|tr -d "\r" >1.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that you have dos (`^M`) line endings, in the file. Running `dos2unix dirs.txt dirs.txt` should solve the problem. Ideally, you also shouldn't use `for line in $(cat ...`, but something like

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  find "$line" -type f \( -name '*good*' -o -exec grep -F "badbad" {} \; \) -exec echo {} \; 
done < dirs.txt
```